# Как найти, кому отправляет Dbms_alert.signal сигнал?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В триггере одной таблицы есть `dbms_alert.signal`.

Почитал документацию, понял что отправляет, и `waitone` его отлавливает.

Вот только не могу найти из-за обширной БД, кто получает сигнал. Просматривать каждый триггер, функцию или процедуру трудозатратно.

Не я разрабатывал БД.

Есть ли способ найти, где это зарегестрированно или прослушивается?

---

Стоит Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сведения о регистрации должны сохраняться в [`SYS.DBMS_ALERT_INFO`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBMS_ALERT_INFO.html#GUID-D78D4360-5E28-4965-B74D-767DE769E5E8). По этой таблице, возможно, получится найти сессии и уже по сессиям понять кто именно ожидает сигнала. Не думаю что есть легкий способ получить более подробную информацию.

> ... проходить каждый триггер,функцию, процедуры не реально.

Обычно исходные тексты доступны через [`ALL_SOURCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_SOURCE.html). Можете попробовать запросом найти все упоминания `DBMS_ALERT`. Другое дело, что регистрация не обязательно выполняется в Ваших функциях/процедурах.

Кроме этого можно посмотреть у каких ролей/пользователей есть права на `DBMS_ALERT` через [`DBA_TAB_PRIVS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_TAB_PRIVS.html)